# Equivalent definitions of semisimplicity of finite dimensional modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $k$-algebra, and let $V$ be a finite dimensional $A$-module. How do we show that $V$ is semisimple (i.e. is the direct sum of simple submodules) if every *maximal* submodule of $V$ has a complement in $V$?

I know the standard proof without the "maximal" condition imposed, but I'm trying to adapt the proof to this to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a maximal submodule $M_1$ and let $C_1$ be its complement, so that $V=M_1\oplus C_1$. Then pick a maximal submodule $M_2$ of $M_1$. Then $M_2\oplus C_1$ is maximal in $V$ (prove this) and so has a complement, $D_2$. Let $C_2$ be the projection of $D_2$ onto $M_1$. Then $V=M_2\oplus C_1 \oplus C_2$. Continue in this way until you have broken down the whole module, which you will eventually achieve since it is finite dimensional.